# Flask application deployment with Azure

Tags: azure, flask, deployment, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

First of all I would like to say that this is my first time making a deployment and I have limited knowledge with Azure deployment, but nonetheless I have to do it and I really need help.

I tried looking for information on how to deploy both a Flask app and a Dash app (my case) but I don't get to a result.

So the context is this: 
I have a Dash application that is the UI. From this UI, requests are made to a Flask app backend, along with some payloads. In the Flask backend, there are multiple app routes where the UI makes requests, depending on the options the user chooses. These payloads are processed in the backend and finally returns the request to the UI.
The backend, as well as the UI, uses multiple modules added in the repository.

Now I researched and I narrowed it down to deployment with Azure App Services or Azure functions. (App Services for UI and Azure functions for backend) I also have a subscription and a resource group already created that I use.
The problem is I do not understand how to deploy such a big code as mine with Azure. All the examples I have found only have a flask app with a single app.route returning 'hello world' and are short on details and explanations.

Could you please help me with either an example that fits my context or some instructions on how to approach this or other resources?

PS: If there is anything else needed, I will add them if necessary.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

1. Flask can be used as the web framework for your Dash application. Create a flask application and deploy it to Azure as detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=flask,windows,vscode-aztools,vscode-deploy,deploy-instructions-azportal,terminal-bash,deploy-instructions-zip-azcli).
2. Upload your [Dash app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-spaces/quickstart-deploy-web-app?tabs=app-service) to the Azure App Service.
3. For your Flask backend, create a Python Azure Function.
4. Deploy your Flask backend on Azure Function. Steps to refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python?tabs=browser#customize-build-automation)  for deploying Flask backend to the Azure Function.
5. Once your Dash application and Flask backend have been deployed, you can configure them to communicate with one another. The `URL` of your Flask backend can be used as the endpoint for your Dash application to make requests to.

*Using all of the above, I tried to verify that the flask deployment was running and deploying, and it did so as shown.*

[image]

[image]

Comment: The thing is I have this repo with backend folder and in this folder i have multiple folders with .py files. In one of the folders is the service.py where the flask functions are. I still don't see how can I deploy this as Azure function.

Comment: Did you try the flask environment for deploying dash application?